# how do you set the innerhtml on a generic control (div) in c# code behind?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am trying to add control (div) dynamically to a web page:

```
 HtmlControl divControl = new html HtmlGenericControl("div");
 divControl.Attributes.Add("id", lb.Items[i].Value);
 divControl.Attributes.Add("innerHtml", "bob");
 divControl.Visible = true;
 this.Controls.Add(divControl);
```

But how do I set the text (innerhtml) of the control itself as it doesn't seem to have as innerHtml as an attribute doesn't exist and there is no 'value' or 'text' options shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you change the type of "divControl" to HtmlGenericControl, you should be able to set the InnerHtml property:

```
HtmlGenericControl divControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
```

Comment: I don't get InnerHtml as an option in the dropdown, and shows an error when I compile which is why I asked as this is what I would have thought would be the answer.

Comment: Are you still declaring divControl as an HtmlControl? That class doesn't have an option for InnerHtml. You would want to change the declaration to: HtmlGenericControl divControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

Answer (score 3):

You'll do it by inserting a [LiteralControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) within the HtmlControl:

```
HtmlControl divControl = new html HtmlGenericControl("div");
divControl.Attributes.Add("id", lb.Items[i].Value);
divControl.Visible = true; // Not really necessary
this.Controls.Add(divControl);

divControl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span>Put whatever <em>HTML</em> code here.</span>"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    HtmlGenericControl divControl = new  HtmlGenericControl("div");
    divControl.Attributes.Add("id", "myDiv");
    divControl.InnerText = "foo";
    this.Controls.Add(divControl);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just adding text, this should do it:

```
Literal l = new Literal();
l.Text = "bob";

HtmlControl divControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divControl.Attributes.Add("id", "someId");
divControl.Visible = true;
divControl.Controls.Add(l);

this.Controls.Add(divControl);
```

Edit: you can embed HTML in a literal as well.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way of adding generic html controls (by using Literal):

```
Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = string.Format(@"<div id='{0}'><span>some text</span></div>", lb.Items[i].Value) });
```